# How do I change retention label into sharepoint with powershell with script for all the files in a specific site

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, retention

I need to change the retention label in a specific site into the sharepoint. I took the following script and I edited it to suit my needs, with some small changes.

It is working but currently it applies the retention only to the folders and subfolders. Is there any way to modify the script in order to apply the retention label to the files in the folders as well?

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url = https://<tenant>-my.sharepoint.com/

Connect-PnPOnline -Url SiteUrl

$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
$web = $Context.Web
$Context.Load($Web)

Set-PnPLabel -List "Documents" -Label "My Label"

$Folder = Get-PnPFolder -Url "Documents/My Shared Documents"
$Folder.ListItemAllFields.SetComplianceTagWithNoHold("My Label")
Invoke-PnPQuery`
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have access to sharepoint to test but try adding `-SyncToItems $true` to the Set-PnPLabel line.  Have a look here for exact usage [Set-PnPLabel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnplabel?view=sharepoint-ps)

Comment: Hello Daniel , i have tried and it works to the files that they don't have any label on it, so partially is fine , but some of the files they have some other label that i need to replace and it not apply , i tried to reset the label using Reset-PnPLabel but seems is not apply this command to any files.

Answer (score 0):

`Set-PnPListItem -Identity $Item -ClearLabel` worked when I needed to clear labels from OneDrive files.